# Matplotlib event picker - Inside a class

Tags: python, events, matplotlib, picker

I am trying to insert the event picker example shown in this python documentation, inside a class

http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html

The code goes like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Test:
    def __init__(self,line):
        self.line = line
        self.cidpress = self.line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onpick)

    def onpick(self, event):
        thisline = event.artist
        xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
        ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
        ind = event.ind
        points = tuple(zip(xdata[ind], ydata[ind]))
        print('onpick points:', points)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click on points')

line, = ax.plot(np.random.rand(10), 'o', picker=5)  # 5 points tolerance
a = Test(line)

plt.show()
```

But Im getting this error when mouse is clicked on a point.

```
AttributeError: 'MouseEvent' object has no attribute 'artist'
```

What could be the reason for this ? 
When not inside the class the code works perfectly

thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that the code works outside a class. The problem you face here is that you use a `'button_press_event'`, which does not have an `artist` attribute. This will not change whether in or outside a class.

- If you want to use the `event.artist` you would need to use a `'pick_event'`. This is shown in the [event picking example](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html#simple-picking-example) on the matplotlib page.
- If you want to use a `'button_press_event'`, you cannot use `event.artist` but would rather need to find out the element which has been clicked upon by querying whether some artist contains the event, e.g. `if line.contains(event)[0]: ...`. See e.g. this question: [How to check if click is on scatter plot point with multiple markers (matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017568/how-to-check-if-click-is-on-scatter-plot-point-with-multiple-markers-matplotlib)

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.  Works like a charm. Cant believe I spent whole day on this.